# Cannot find module - Error when running tests on react project

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, create-react-app

When i run `yarn test` locally on my React project i get this error (project is created with Create react app):

> Cannot find module <project_directory>node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault

Everything was normal and after adding `react-responsive` package, my tests started failing like this.
Even though they show that they *fail*, when i choose to run only failed tests, they don't run again. It's like they failed in their own way but not concerning the test process.

On the side note, when my tests run on CI/CD pipeline, they work with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking into consideration that CI/CD pipeline test run succeeds, i got to thinking that it could have to do something with my local environment.

Solution is to first clear cache in tests and than run tests again:

```
yarn test --clearCache
```

And that run

```
yarn test
```

**NPM variant**:

```
npm test -- --clearCache
```

And everything works fine now.

I found out on this issue that regards on a similar error but for a different module.
[This answer gave me a solution](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7183#issuecomment-581400477)

[Issue in on create react app repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7183)

Comment: im having opposite problem. my tests runs good locally but fails on github cicd. Same error module cannot be found